# Allowed to send email through own webserver iOS 7?

Tags: php, ios, iphone, objective-c, email

is it Allowed to send email through your own webserver on iOS 7 ?
So, what I want to say is that I Don't want to use the standard iOS mail popup dialog because people may not see the users email address they are sending the email to.

Thnx in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you'd have to create the SMTP mail connection yourself, (not using MFMailComposer). There are no UIKit Classes to create/send mail through arbitrary mailservers, thus there is no way to send an email without using third-party-libraries.

Look into [SKPSMTPMessage](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage), or failing that I can recommend [mailcore](http://libmailcore.com/), it's easy to set up and use. Used it once and worked like a charme. You can find the code on github containing examples [here](https://github.com/mronge/MailCore).

Comment: Thank you !, yes i will setup my own mail server and do an ajax call, i'am using Titanium Apcellerator for this project. so i can do a call to a remote php file.

Comment: @user3306184 sounds good! Please mark the answer as correct if you are happy with the solution.